# calling multiple functions within group_walk()

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been using group_walk() to make plots of split sections of a dataframe within a dplyr pipe. This has been working well but I can't figure out how to add multiple functions for each split section.

I have a dataframe

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(rnorm(5),5), y = rep(rnorm(5),5), col = rep(c(1:5),5), 
                lab = rep(c('a','b','c','d','e'),5),
                section = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5),rep(3,5),rep(4,5),rep(5,5)))
##group_walk plotting
df %>% 
  group_by(section) %>%
  group_walk(~ plot(.x$y~.x$x, col = .x$col))
```

What I would like to add is a second function within group_walk to add a legend to each subplot, something like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(section) %>%
  group_walk(~ plot(.x$y~.x$x, col = .x$col),
             ~ legend('bottomright',col = .x$col, legend = .x$lab))
```

But I don't know what the appropriate syntax is for this. I'd prefer working within dplyr pipes as opposed to going back to for loops. Is there a way to do this or does group_walk not support multiple function calls for each section of the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option would be to use braces (`{}`) to keep it as a single block

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
 group_by(section)  %>% 
 group_walk(~ {
    plot(.x$y ~ .x$x, col = .x$col)
    legend('bottomright', col = .x$col, legend = .x$lab)
  })
```

[image]

---

Note that in the formula, we can pass the column name if we specify the `data` as parameter and this will also remove the `.x$` in the plot axis title

```
df %>%
    group_by(section)  %>% 
    group_walk(~ {
        plot(y ~ x, col = col, data = .x)
        legend('bottomright', col = .x$col, legend = .x$lab)
   })
```

---

To create the `title` with group values, use `cur_group_id`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(section) %>% 
  mutate(grp_value = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  group_walk(~ {plot(y ~ x, col = col, data = .x,
    main = first(.x$grp_value))})
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain the `section` value (i.e. the name of each group) e.g. to use it as title of the plot?

Comment: @zeawoas you may use `cur_group()` to extract the group

Comment: Could you maybe edit the answer to show how this would be done without throwing ```Error: `cur_group()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.```?

Comment: @zeawoas You can do `df %>% group_by(section) %>% mutate(grp_value = cur_group_id()) %>% group_walk(~ {plot(y ~ x, col = col, data = .x, main = first(.x$grp_value))})`